# How to access the namespace instead of the class?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class named `store` and a namespace named `store`. When I try to access the `mynamespace.store.makeRequesty` from the `mynamespace.modal.store` class, TypeScript cannot find it.

**A.ts**

```
namespace mynamespace.modal {
    export class store() {
        public constructor() {
            store.makeRequest()
        }
    }
}
```

**B.ts**

```
namespace mynamespace.store {
    export function makeRequest() {
        // Makes an http request
    }
}
```

> Property 'makeRequest' does not exist on type 'typeof store'.

I tried calling it like `mynamespace.store.makeRequest()` but then I get the following error:

> Property 'store' does not exist on type 'typeof mynamespace'.

What way is there for me to access the `store namespace` and not the `store class`?

**Edit**

I tried attaching the namespace to the window:

```
interface Window {
  mynamespace: mynamespace
}
```

However, I get the following error:

> [ts] Cannot find name 'mynamespace'.
>   [ts] Property 'mynamespace' of exported interface has or is using private name 'mynamespace'.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

A.ts

```
namespace mynamespace.modal {
  export class store {
      public constructor() {
        mynamespace.store.makeRequest()
      }
  }
}
```

B.ts

```
namespace mynamespace {
  export namespace store {
    export function makeRequest() {
      // Makes an http request
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: which of the errors are above are you still getting? try removing the `Window` interface extension, it's unnecessary.  also, what version of TS are you using?

Comment: The issues is because I had a class that was named the same as the namespace so `name.name` and it was getting confused. I renamed the class and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `import` to create an alias and avoid the name conflict:

```js
namespace mynamespace.store {
    export function makeRequest() {
        // Makes an http request
    }
}

namespace mynamespace.modal {
    import makeRequest = mynamespace.store.makeRequest;
    export class store {
        public constructor() {
            makeRequest();
        }
    }
}
```